# Middle point of each pair of an numpy.array

Tags: python, numpy, mean

I have an array of the form:

```py
x = np.array([ 1230.,  1230.,  1227.,  1235.,  1217.,  1153.,  1170.])
```

and I would like to produce another array where the values are the mean of each pair of values within my original array:

```py
xm = np.array([ 1230.,  1228.5,  1231.,  1226.,  1185.,  1161.5])
```

Someone knows the easiest and fast way to do it without using loops?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Even shorter, slightly sweeter:

```
(x[1:] + x[:-1]) / 2
```

---

- **This is faster:**

  ```
  >>> python -m timeit -s "import numpy; x = numpy.random.random(1000000)" "x[:-1] + numpy.diff(x)/2"
  100 loops, best of 3: 6.03 msec per loop

  >>> python -m timeit -s "import numpy; x = numpy.random.random(1000000)" "(x[1:] + x[:-1]) / 2"
  100 loops, best of 3: 4.07 msec per loop
  ```
- **This is perfectly accurate:**

  Consider each element in `x[1:] + x[:-1]`. So consider `x₀` and `x₁`, the first and second elements.

  `x₀ + x₁` is calculated to perfect precision and *then* rounded, in accordance to IEEE. It would therefore be the correct answer if that was all that was needed.

  `(x₀ + x₁) / 2` is just half of that value. This can almost always be done by reducing the exponent by one, except in two cases:

  - `x₀ + x₁` overflows. This will result in an infinity (of either sign). That's not what is wanted, so the calculation will be **wrong**.
  - `x₀ + x₁` underflows. As the size is *reduced*, rounding will be perfect and thus the calculation will be **correct**.

  In all other cases, the calculation will be **correct**.

  ---

  Now consider `x[:-1] + numpy.diff(x) / 2`. This, by inspection of the source, evaluates directly to

  ```
  x[:-1] + (x[1:] - x[:-1]) / 2
  ```

  and so consider again `x₀` and `x₁`.

  `x₁ - x₀` will have severe "problems" with *underflow* for many values. This will also lose precision with large cancellations. It's not immediately clear that this doesn't matter if the signs are the same, though, as the error effectively cancels out on addition. What does matter is that *rounding occurs*.

  `(x₁ - x₀) / 2` will be no less rounded, but then `x₀ + (x₁ - x₀) / 2` involves *another* rounding. This means that errors *will* creep in. Proof:

  ```
  import numpy

  wins = draws = losses = 0

  for _ in range(100000):
      a = numpy.random.random()
      b = numpy.random.random() / 0.146

      x = (a+b)/2 
      y = a + (b-a)/2

      error_mine   = (a-x) - (x-b)
      error_theirs = (a-y) - (y-b)

      if x != y:
          if abs(error_mine) < abs(error_theirs):
              wins += 1
          elif abs(error_mine) == abs(error_theirs):
              draws += 1
          else:
              losses += 1
      else:
          draws += 1

  wins / 1000
  #>>> 12.44

  draws / 1000
  #>>> 87.56

  losses / 1000
  #>>> 0.0
  ```

  This shows that for the carefully chosen constant of `1.46`, a full 12-13% of answers are wrong with the `diff` variant! As expected, my version is always right.

  Now consider *underflow*. Although my variant has overflow problems, these are much less big a deal than cancellation problems. It should be obvious why the double-rounding from the above logic is very problematic. Proof:

  ```
  ...
      a = numpy.random.random()
      b = -numpy.random.random()
  ...

  wins / 1000
  #>>> 25.149

  draws / 1000
  #>>> 74.851

  losses / 1000
  #>>> 0.0
  ```

  Yeah, it gets 25% wrong!

  In fact, it doesn't take much pruning to get this up to 50%:

  ```
  ...
      a = numpy.random.random()
      b = -a + numpy.random.random()/256
  ...

  wins / 1000
  #>>> 49.188

  draws / 1000
  #>>> 50.812

  losses / 1000
  #>>> 0.0
  ```

  Well, it's not that bad. It's only ever 1 least-significant-bit off *as long as the signs are the same*, I think.

---

So there you have it. My answer is the best unless you're finding the average of two values whose sum exceeds `1.7976931348623157e+308` or is smaller than `-1.7976931348623157e+308`.

Comment: It's probably not too relevant in practical applications, but I think this is both slightly faster than @JohnZwinck's answer, and also slightly more prone to loss of precision.

Comment: @Jaime You're wrong. Mine *is* faster, but it's also perfectly accurate, whereas the `diff` version is not. I'll add some evidence to the question.

Comment: @Jaime Evidence added.

Comment: If it is efficiency you are looking for, I would even suggest `.5 * (x[1:] + x[:-1])`, since the float product is faster than the float division.

Comment: @Iago-lito Marginal gains; this is only a 4% increase in throughput for a noticeable loss of clarity. Much less than the 50% increase in throughput and improvement of clarity my original suggestion gave. I guess if you're in a rush, though.

Comment: @Veedrac I guess it also depend on your machine and on the length of `x` compared to the length of the loop. I reduced the time by 30% with my tests (long `x` and short loop).. Maybe it's worth checking in any specific case whether or not readability beats efficiency as far as `.5 * x` vs `x / 2` is concerned ;)

Comment: Just a suggestions: Add the decimal point for the `2` in the division such that it also works for integer arrays `x`. We see that problem A LOT when tutoring python beginners...

Comment: @obachtos A better suggestion: use a modern Python version.

Comment: @Veedrac Valid point. But reality is that python 2.x is still widely used.

Answer (score 11):

Short and sweet:

```
x[:-1] + np.diff(x)/2
```

That is, take each element of `x` except the last, and add one-half of the difference between it and the subsequent element.

Comment: I posted 9 seconds before you did, though I must admit you gave a better explanation!

Comment: I would have posted 9 seconds before you if I had just clicked the button as soon as I had typed the code!  :)  It's pretty cool that we wrote the exact same solution, meanwhile a couple other people came up with pretty different ideas, and I have to say each one of them has its own special appeal.  I still like ours though!

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
midpoints = x[:-1] + np.diff(x)/2
```

It's pretty easy and should be fast.

Answer (score 2):

If speed matters, use multiplication instead of division, following Veedrac answer:

```
    0.5 * (x[:-1] + x[1:])
```

Profiling results:

```
    >>> python -m timeit -s "import numpy; x = numpy.random.random(1000000)" "0.5 * (x[:-1] + x[1:])"
    100 loops, best of 3: 4.20 msec per loop

    >>> python -m timeit -s "import numpy; x = numpy.random.random(1000000)" "(x[:-1] + x[1:]) / 2"
    100 loops, best of 3: 5.10 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = np.array([ 1230., 1230., 1227., 1235., 1217., 1153., 1170.])

>>> (x+np.concatenate((x[1:], np.array([0]))))/2
array([ 1230. ,  1228.5,  1231. ,  1226. ,  1185. ,  1161.5,   585. ])
```

now you can just strip the last element, if you want

Answer (score 0):

I end up using this operation a bunch on multi-dimensional arrays so I'll post my solution (inspired by the source code for `np.diff()`)

```
def zcen(a, axis=0):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    nd = a.ndim
    slice1 = [slice(None)]*nd
    slice2 = [slice(None)]*nd
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, None)
    slice2[axis] = slice(None, -1)
    return (a[slice1]+a[slice2])/2

>>> a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]]
>>> zcen(a)
array([[  5.5,  11. ,  16.5,  22. ,  27.5]])
>>> zcen(a, axis=1)
array([[  1.5,   2.5,   3.5,   4.5],
       [ 15. ,  25. ,  35. ,  45. ]])
```